# Typescript check array value is in enum1 or enum 2 but not both

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to check if values in `myList` are from `Enum1` or `Enum2` but not both?

```js
enum Enum1 {
  Foo = '1',
}
    
enum Enum2 {
  Bar = '1',
}
    
const myList = (Enum1 | Enum2)[] = [
  Enum1.Foo, // not wanted - '1' appears in Enum1 and Enum2
]
```

Comment: what exactly do you want the output to be? - could you provide an elaborate example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in TypeScript are *inclusive* and not *exclusive*.  A union `A | B` *includes* the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `A & B`.  In other words, the union `A | B` accepts all values of type `A` and all values of type `B`, including any values which are of both types `A` *and* `B`.

It looks like you are trying to represent the *exclusive* union, which specifically *excludes* the intersection.  Something like

```
const myList: ExclusiveUnion<Enum1, Enum2>[] = [ /* ... */ ];
```

---

Unfortunately, you can't write down a fully general `ExclusiveUnion<T, U>` type function that works on all types `T` and `U`.  TypeScript doesn't have direct support for *negated types* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317)), so there's no type operator `not` which specifically excludes types.  If `not` existed, you could write this:

```
// none of this is valid TypeScript, don't try it:
type ExclusiveUnion<T, U> = (T | U) & (not (T & U));
type ExclusiveUnion<T, U> = (T & not U) | (U & not T);
```

But it doesn't, so you can't.

---

However: for the particular case where `T` and `U` are themselves unions of [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) (like `"1" | "2" | null | 3 | undefined | false`), you could  use the [`Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to filter out the members of `T | U` that are assignable to the intersection `T & U`:

```
// this works only when T | U are unions of literal types 
type ExclusiveUnion<T, U> = Exclude<T | U, T & U>
```

So, conceptually, at least, you could write something like

```
type Enum1XorEnum2 = ExclusiveUnion<Enum1, Enum2>
```

since both `Enum1` and `Enum2` types should be similar to a union of literal string/numeric types.  That works conceptually, but in practice, it doesn't.  The problem is that enums are weird.

---

[Enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) values in TypeScript have some fairly strange behavior; see [microsoft/TypeScript#21998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21998) for an issue preventing the above from working.

I really think that enums in TypeScript are best treated as completely opaque.  The fact that `Enum1.Foo` is `"1"` and not `"SomethingElseEntirely"` shouldn't matter to the working of your program; if it does matter, then I'd suggest that `enum` should probably be abandoned in favor of something like a union of literals.

For example, let's look at the following definitions for `Enum1` and `Enum2`, which have a little more structure than your version so that there actually is something we'd like to accept:

```
enum Enum1 {
    Foo = '1',
    Baz = '2',
}

enum Enum2 {
    Bar = '1',
    Qux = '3'
}
```

(So you want `ExclusiveUnion<Enum1, Enum3>` to be `Enum1.Baz | Enum2.Qux`).  Instead of using `enum`, you might be just as happy with the following definitions:

```
const Enum1 = {
    Foo: '1',
    Baz: '2'
} as const;
type Enum1 = typeof Enum1[keyof typeof Enum1];

const Enum2 = {
    Bar: '1',
    Qux: '3'
} as const;
type Enum2 = typeof Enum2[keyof typeof Enum2];
```

This behaves similarly; the values `Enum1` and `Enum2` are objects with key-to-value mappings.  And the types `Enum1` and `Enum2` are just unions of the relevant value types:

```
// type Enum1 = "1" | "2"
// type Enum2 = "1" | "3"
```

If you make that change, then you can use the `ExclusiveUnion` type above and everything will work as desired:

```
type Enum1XorEnum2 = ExclusiveUnion<Enum1, Enum2>
// type Enum1XorEnum2 = "2" | "3"

const myList: Enum1XorEnum2[] = [
    Enum1.Foo, // error
    Enum1.Baz, // okay
    Enum2.Bar, // error
    Enum2.Qux // okay
]
```

Nice!

---

If for some reason you really want to plow ahead with using `enum`s, you will have to jump through some annoying hoops to get a usable type.  You can't just write

```
type Nope = ExclusiveUnion<Enum1, Enum2>; // Enum1 | Enum2
```

because the compiler sees `Enum1 & Enum2` as `never` and changing its mind is quite involved:

```
type Enum1XorEnum2 = Enum1 | Enum2 extends infer T ? (
    T extends string | number ? (
        `${T}` extends `${Enum1}` & `${Enum2}` ? never : T
    ) : never
) : never;
// type Enum1XorEnum2 = Enum1.Baz | Enum2.Qux
```

That works (as long as your `enum`s are just string enums or just numeric enums but not a mixture of both), but blecch.  It turns the enum values into string literal types and then checks each member of `Enum1 | Enum2` and filters out any member which is found both in the string literal versions of both `Enum1` and `Enum2`.

It works as before:

```
const myList: Enum1XorEnum2[] = [
    Enum1.Foo, // error
    Enum1.Baz, // okay
    Enum2.Bar, // error
    Enum2.Qux // okay
]
```

---

So there you go.  If you really plan to take two separate enums and inspect their values, you can't treat them as opaque, and so I'd strongly suggest you consider switching from an `enum` to a union of literals.  As you can see, they are much easier to deal with.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIBcAsEsGdwHcD2AnA1olA7ANgJ7LQCmO4AKuAD7gCq4AhmieAK46y7YBm4esSCTSM8UAgAcSiYJEmsAogA8AxnjbxYANxJ1OuADwUANPQB84ALzhlatgBMSRmvVNUAZOeDAcjALbSEowqrAAygsKiAJI48EKM9uAA3t7A4OngKtyQNjhsfgCMVslpGWUAYigoAFzgAOQFdcalZekAQowAXrV1AEx1LeAAvkyIWbGQANyDclK5+UXWsyQofAp5hQDaGCQEq+JS++sLALrTg+Nx8369xSmtGR1oPY3ND+kAimxKPQDMA2URowxtlpmVltdbkt5EcNr1trt9stYflemdvGUwAdFBtFuAAEQFfEufG9fGDLEQ443YqE4m0fG-ckzeTXAoADXQ1KhNlU6k0Oj0XBwBmpBVM3LMFIgVNxnLQ3NpZJJTIxGUuOT8BHCcVqYvl3M2J2Km0GZTFADpKihTFjhGh0GaMpaOp1bRAUBhGAQneluRanu7wPbHe9IRavkpwFjPd7BidvENUr4AvAgiFwABBFSQNiiamIFKDMj5NklMPW4oNJq+8Cuqv9N4ZJPFjaQ8vvJ5V161yNV-6DFvg1kAORQc2stn52l0+hFYolcLMk2jEDFLm5LLmI5IOjQxXXnm5K6xOF3wjV6VlCwNcIPuI3d5ISiEOHsiFgOB4wko4AA-OAAAUtZUM+r7vuAcRoJ+ADmLgbAARj+AHAWGZQAAYACRJBQQzocGL5kBBWFJGKeHgJ4JHcuRAFnnu4C1BQtYAJQMeAdEXmUrG1BxaBghklKsvqXJ3pOuIBl0j6ohG3ypGUGrgFqOqQHqcoiaiRomrWlrWkGIZoNp4mukGsY+mG-qBquwZoA6BnmXCMlRjGXpmRkCbAEMQA)